# jprofiler \ jpcontroller cannot connect to MBean server

Tags: tomcat, mbeans, jprofiler

I'm trying to use jpcontroller to connect to a local app, but I'm getting an error message that it cannot connect to the MBean server.  My configuration details are below:

I've addded the following arguments to my tcServer \ Tomcat startup config:

```
wrapper.java.additional.10="-agentpath:C:\PROGRA~1\JPROFI~1\bin\WINDOW~1\jprofilerti.dll=offline,id=121"
wrapper.java.additional.11="-Djprofiler.jmxServerPort=5555"
```

Here is the tcServer \ Tomcat startup output:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Protocol version 35
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Using JVMTI
jvm 1    | JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> 64-bit library
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Offline profiling mode.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Using config file C:\XXXXX\XXXXXX\.jprofiler7\config.xml (id: 121)
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Native library initialized
jvm 1    | JProfiler> VM initialized
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Using sampling (5 ms)
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
jvm 1    | JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Hotspot compiler enabled
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | JProfiler> WARNING: No authentication for JMX server specified.
jvm 1    | JProfiler> Pass -Djprofiler.jmxPasswordFile=[file] to set up authentication
jvm 1    | Jul 29, 2013 9:32:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
jvm 1    | INFO: Initialization processed in 974 ms
```

Based on the docs I assumed that the jprofiler.jmxPasswordFile argument is optional, so I disregarded the message pertaining to authentication for the JMX server.  Unfortunately when I run jpcontroller it is not able to connect to the MBean server.  Here is the output:

```
Connecting to XXXXXXXXXXXX:5555 ...
No connection to an MBean server at XXXXXXXXXXXX:5555 could be made
If the remote computer is only reachable via an IP address, please add
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[IP address] as a VM parameter to the remote VM
```

I also connected to the JVM with JConsole and did not see any com.jprofiler MBeans registered.  Does anything else need to be configured besides the jprofiler.jmxServerPort argument?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Aaron

Comment: You should contact the vendor for support. Their response time is quite good.